# How to query kafka streams state store correctly?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have built a kafka-streams application with 20 streams threads a month ago. This app calculates the consumption of different people in a fixed time interval. Recently I found the people's spend money that is queried form local state store is less than real. I have read official, and any other documents I could find, but have not found the solve method.

I used Kafka version 0.11.0.3, kafka server's version is 0.11.0.3, and kafka streams api is also 0.11.0.3. Only one application with 20 streams threads.

### Some important info:

Kafka streams config:

- replication.factor            3
- num.stream.threads            20
- commit.interval.ms            1000
- partition.assignment.strategy StickyAssignor.class.getName()
- fetch.max.wait.ms             500
- max.poll.records              5000
- max.poll.interval.ms          300000
- heartbeat.interval.ms         3000
- session.timeout.ms            30000
- auto.offset.reset             latest

kafka message structure

- key = person's name
- value = the money he spend
- time = the current time that this message was created

Kafka streams build code:

```java
KStreamBuilder kStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, Double> peopleSpendStream = kStreamBuilder.stream(topic);
peopleSpendStream.groupByKey()// group by people's name
        .aggregate(() -> new HashMap<String, Double>(8192),
                (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                    aggregate.merge(key, value, Double::sum);
                    return aggregate;
                },
                TimeWindows.of(ONE_MINUTE).until(ONE_HOUR * 10), // 1-min window, keep 9 hours
                new HashMapSerde<>(), // serialize and deserialize by jackson actually
                PEOPLE_SPEND_STORE_NAME);
```

Query code:

```java
long time = System.currentTimeMilles();
for (String name : names) { // query by people's name
    try (WindowStoreIterator<HashMap<String, Double>> iterator = store.fetch(name, time - TEN_MINUTE_MILLES, time)) {
        iterator.forEachRemaining(kv -> log.info("name = {}, time = {}, cost = {}", name, kv.key, kv.value));
    }
}
```

Is anything I get wrong? I need your help in particular.

Comment: https://streamthoughts.github.io/azkarra-streams/

Comment: Your aggregate window is an hour, but you are fetching a 10 minute window in the query?

Comment: how can i change aggregate window to a minute? I set 'TimeWindows.of(ONE_MINUTE).until(ONE_HOUR * 10)'

Comment: I read the azkarra-streams document, it requires jdk11 and kafka 2.x, but i use jdk8 and kafka0.11.0.3...

Comment: Okay, well, you can use Kafka 2.x clients with older broker versions down to 0.11.0 and Java 8 is end of life...